# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [admin_theme_fragment] was found

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsf, joinfaces

I am stuck on how to fix this error. It might be a duplicate question but the [solution](https://exerror.com/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring_web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-with-relative-ordering/) offered I don't know how to configure it in join faces and spring boot as am not using web.xml. [Here](https://pastebin.com/gPn7SQHA) is my pom XML and below is my application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/School
joinfaces.primefaces.theme=admin
joinfaces.jsf.project-stage=development
joinfaces.primefaces.csp=true
joinfaces.primefaces.font-awesome=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
joinfaces.myfaces.clear-input-when-submitted-value-is-null-or-empty=true
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
server.max-http-header-size=10MB
server.port=8443
security.require-ssl=true
```

and here is the full stack trace of the error am getting when i try to deploy to external tomcat. When I run from IDE it works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use an IDE, search in your files for the word `admin_theme_fragment`. You should use it once in your code but instead you have used it more than one time.

Rename it accordingly.

Comment: have realized this admin_theme_fragment is in admin-theme am using dont know how to get it ignored